# How to save files directly from Windows programs to USB connected Android smartphone?

Tags: android, windows, save, savefiledialog

From my Windows computer I can open a file stored on a connected USB smartphone (Android) with any software, with the "open file" dialog. But the phone does not appear in the "save file" dialogs... of course I can first save on the PC, then drag and drop files to the phone with Windows file explorer, but I'd like to save directly to the phone from the software.

Is there a setting somewhere to solve this, on Windows or Android side ?

Else what is the reason, it seems that security wise the opposite would be more appropriate, and if Windows has write privileges on the USB connected phone, why not the Windows software ?

Windows 10 Home & Pro editions, several Android phones.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a question about how to use an Android device and Windows, not how to program for either of them

Comment: THose are all using.  Unless you plan on writing a file explorer that does it programatically, you're talking about using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the short answer is you can't do that easily : since Android has switched to ext4 file system, Windows can not get exclusive access to it, which is required for a USB mass storage protocol (and mount the phone partition as a separate drive, ie E:).
Older Android versions established a partition for their system, and a separate partition for storage that could be shared with exclusive access for the computer...
The only way seems to be to root your Android phone and install some utility app.